# Why forEach shows me dubbled output? (React.Children.forEach method)

Tags: reactjs, foreach

I have this code that shows me text in console twice. Why?

```
const { Children } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM

const Display = ({children}) => Children.forEach(children, child => 
      console.log(child.props.children))

render(
    <Display> 
         <h1>Child 1</h1> 
         <h1>Child 2</h1> 
         <h1>Child 3</h1> 
    </Display>
, document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

Console shows this:
Child 1 
Child 2 
Child 3
Child 1 
Child 2 
Child 3

Comment: Possibly due to re rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No valid value was returned from `Display` which resulted in unexpected behaviour from `ReactDom.render`. Add a `return null` in `Display`.